# Blazor: Invoking C# static method from JS function called from HTML onclick--why can't the JS find the method?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

Inside a Blazor component, I want to call a JS method from the HTML onclick event of an anchor tag, thus:

```
<a onclick="window.LoadImage();" class="@CssClass">@DisplayName</a>
```

My JS method is:

```
window.LoadImage = () => {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MyProject', 'FireEvent').then();
}
```

Inside the JS method, I want to fire a C# static method to trigger an event, thus:

```
[JSInvokable]
public static void FireEvent()
{
   StateEngine.LoadImage(DisplayName, Target);
}
[Parameter]
public string DisplayName { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string Target { get; set; }
```

I can't get the JS method to find the C# method. I've tried multiple name configurations for the first parameter, like

```
MyProject (the assembly name)
MyProject.FolderName.ComponentName
FolderName.ComponentName
ComponentName
```

to name a few. I've also tried shuffling names through the second parameter.

How is this supposed to work? What am I missing?

P.S. Please disregard the bit about the instance properties in the static method.  I've got a workaround for that, but don't want to clutter up the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you would be better off using the reference JSInterop so you can access the components properties.

Razor

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@implements IDisposable

 <a @onclick=Clicked>Click here</a>

@code
{
  private DotNetObjecctReference ObjRef;

  [JSInvokable]
  public void FireEvent()
  {
     StateEngine.LoadImage(DisplayName, Target);
  }

  private Task Clicked()
  {
    return JS.InvokeVoidAsync("window.LoadImage", ObjRef);
  }

  protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    ObjRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
  }

  void IDisposable.Dispose()
  {
    ObjRef.Dispose();
  }
}
```

JS

```
window.LoadImage = (dotNetObject) => {
    dotNetObject.invokeMethod('FireEvent');
}
```

Comment: If you create a DotNetObjectReference without disposing it, you app will leak memory - https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-dotnet-from-javascript/lifetimes-and-memory-leaks/

Comment: @PeterMorris Thanks, edited. For anyone reading this, there are multiple ways you could handle the DotNetObjectReference creation. 

Creating a new object every js call(and disposing inside the JS) is one method. 

The link in Peter's above post shows another way using a component property and implementing IDisposable.

Comment: I revised it slightly. I think it's impolite to dispose of objects you didn't create. I hope you don't mind and will accept my modifications - but I don't mind if you revert them :)

Comment: This gave me enough to go on; but then I had the rug pulled out from under me, and this project is on "eternal hold".

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. May be its unable to find your .Net method. Give it a retry..

**JS**

```
window.LoadImage = function () {
DotNet.invokeMethodAsync("MyBlazorProject.UI", "FireEvent").then();}
```

First Parameter must be AssemblyName of your Blazor component. In my case, it is "MyBlazorProject.UI".
Second Parameter must be method name.

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="window.LoadImage()" class="btn btn-primary">Call .Net Method FireEvent</a>
```

here onclick is JavaScript event, which is good in your case too.

**C# Code**

```
[JSInvokable]
public static void FireEvent()
{
    //debugger hits here
    //StateEngine.LoadImage(DisplayName, Target);
}
```

This is all working for me fine. Debugger gets hit inside FireEvent .Net method after clicking anchor tag.

[image: output]

Thanks